# Display Web style number of records in a Winform

Tags: c#, winforms

My requirement is to display the individual record numbers that that are in my table at the bottom of a WinForm. The same as we have in Web where we display the numbers of records as the bottom of a gridview like below. 
                 Prev 1 2 3 4 5 Next
I have some TextBox controls which display data from a table. When the user clicks on the Record number at the bottom of the form, the TextBox controls should display the next/previous record.

Comment: This is close: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/bindingnavigator-control-overview-windows-forms

Comment: `BindingNavigator` could be hijacked to work, but it's really made for binding to a data source, like a `DataTable`.  There is no single answer to this.  You have to make this yourself, from the ground up.

Answer (score 0):

Did I understood you right? You have the some dataset (for example the 50 string values) and you wanna add to table just part of this dataset (for example show only 10 values in the table) and show first 1-10, then 20-30 and so on.

In this case you can use linq for taking data.

```
var dataset = new List<string>(){"data1", "data2" ... , "data50"}
//You can use NumericUpDown to switch pages, in this case:

var showedList = dataset 
   .Skip((numericUpDown.Value-1)*10)
   .Take(10);
```

and next you can show only selected data

Comment: No. I am not trying to add anything to the dataset. I am trying to display the numbers of records in the dataset which is already populated. So, if i have 10 records, then in my form, I need to display numbers like 1 2 3 4 5...10. Which when the user clicks on any number the data in the Textbox in the form should be moved either to next or previous record. Just as we have the search result in Google footer which shows the number of records/pages .

Comment: check this out - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/bindingnavigator-control-windows-forms